# using Array_append gives me syntax error when creating PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, arrays

Here is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION primes (IN   integer) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    counter INTEGER = $1;
    primes int [];
    mycount int;
  BEGIN
    WHILE counter != 0 LOOP
      mycount := count(primes);
      array_append(primes [counter], mycount);
      counter := counter - 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN array_to_text(primes[], ',');
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

This is me developing the beginnings of a prime generating function. I am trying to simply get it to return the 'count' of the array. So if I pass '7' into the function I should get back [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

But when I try to create this function I get

```
SQL Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "array_append" LINE 1: array_append( $1  [ $2 ],  $3 )
        ^ QUERY:  array_append( $1  [ $2 ],  $3 ) CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "primes" near line 8
```

I am a newbie with postgres functions. I am not understanding why I cannnot get this array to work properly.

Again all I want is to just fill this array up correctly with the 'current' count of the array. (It's more to just help me understand that it is in fact doing the loop correctly and is counting it correctly).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you using a Database to generate Primes?!?

Comment: I presume that you're only doing this to learn PL/SQL - I think SO would be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Yes I am just doing this to learn.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

> **Function**: `array_append(anyarray, anyelement)`
>   **Return Type**: `anyarray`
>   **Description**: append an element to the end of an array

So `array_append` returns an array and you need to assign that return value to something. Also, I think you want `array_to_string` at the end of your function, not `array_to_text`. And `primes` is an array so you want `array_append(primes, mycount)` rather than trying to append to an entry in `primes`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION primes (IN integer) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    counter INTEGER = $1; 
    primes int []; 
    mycount int; 
BEGIN
    WHILE counter != 0 LOOP 
        mycount := count(primes); 
        primes  := array_append(primes, mycount);
        counter := counter - 1; 
    END LOOP;
    RETURN array_to_string(primes, ',');   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I don't know what you intend `mycount := count(primes);` to do, perhaps you meant to say `mycount := array_length(primes, 1);` so that you would get a sequence of consecutive integers in `primes`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you that was my problem(s). And yes I was looking for array_length - I am trying to learn SQL programming syntax. It's a whole new world.

Comment: @StanQA: You might want to have a look at [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) for producing sequences. You'd have to think in terms of sets/tables rather than loops but that's how you have to approach SQL anyway.