# How can i add into database column array from ruby on rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have to following method

```
before_save :save_each_item_details

def save_each_item_details
  items = itemname.length
  i = 0

  while i < items
    items = itemname.length
    if !ItemsCensu.exists?(itname: itemname[i], year: "#{date.to_s.split('-').first}")
      ItemsCensu.create(itname: itemname[i], monadaM: mm[i], quntity: quantity[i], price: price[i], tax: tax[i], year: "#{date.to_s.split('-').first}", num_invoice << invoice_num)
      i += 1
    else
      puts "test"
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

`num_invoice` is the array from database. `invoice_num` is a number like `1239`

Each time I save it, I want it to to add the `invoice_num` into `num_invoice[]` without removing the old value.

For example

1st save:

```
invoice_num = 1234
num_invoice << invoice_num
# => 1234
```

2nd save:

```
invoice_num = 12345
num_invoice << invoice_num
# => [1234, 12345]
```

Is there a way to build this into my `ItemsCensu.create`, something like `ItemsCensu.create(num_invoice: << invoice_num)`?

Comment: where does `invoice_num` coming from? Is `num_invoice` database field of current object that you're saving?

Comment: invoice_num coming from the form before the save,  you can say that its like generae a random number, any hard code solution is acceptable

Comment: Well so why doesn't num_invoice << invoice_num work for you?

Comment: this aint working at Exapmple.create(num_invoice << invouce_num) there is the error may it helps you " syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...}", num_invoice << invoice_num) "

Comment: `create` expects a hash of name-value. E.g. `Exapmple.create(num_invoice: num_invoice << invouce_num)`
I'm slightly confused about your data structure, but maybe you want `ItemsCensu.create(itname: itemname[i], <whatever else you have here except last>, num_invoice: [invoice_num]`. Since you create a new object the value of the array will be your new element inside new array.

Comment: Which database are you using? if postgresql then go through the [array functions] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) or [this example] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9680411/12297707)

Comment: Does `items_censu.update_attributes(num_invoice: items_censu.num_invoice + invoice num)` solve your problem? Simply append the value to it's current array before saving